# Not to match with regex in angular if there are any attachments, letters, words at the beginning and(or) end

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular14

Update Question;

First of all hi everyone, i'm new here, i will try hard to get my question right.

how the data came to me;

```
    0: {highWord: 'hafif ticari araçlarda', color: '#00FF00'}
    1: {highWord: 'hafif ticari', color: '#00FF00'}
    2: {highWord: 'kamyon', color: '#00FFFF'}
    3: {highWord: 'MAN', color: '#00FFFF'}
    4: {highWord: 'otobüs', color: '#00FFFF'}
    5: {highWord: 'AĞIR VASITA', color: '#00FFFF'}
    6: {highWord: 'ağır vasıta', color: '#00FFFF'}
    7: {highWord: 'Ağır vasıta', color: '#00FFFF'}
    8: {highWord: 'Ağır Vasıta', color: '#00FFFF'}
```

here is the code block where I match my words;

```
 let searchRgx = new RegExp(this.highlightWordList.map(item => {
      console.log(item)
      return item.highWord;
    }).join("|"), 'gi');
```

this is the output this code gives me

```
/hafif ticari araçlarda|hafif ticari|kamyon|MAN|otobüs|AĞIR VASITA|ağır vasıta|Ağır vasıta|Ağır Vasıta/gi
```

and I paint the matched word here but it matches wrong

```
 let _this = this
  return txt.replace(searchRgx, function (match, offset, string)  {
     
      let foundedKeyword = _this.highlightWordList.filter(item => {
        return item.highWord.toLowerCase() === match.toLowerCase();
      })[0];

      if (foundedKeyword == undefined) {
        foundedKeyword = {};
        foundedKeyword.color = 'white';
      }


      return `<span style='background-color:${foundedKeyword.color};' >${match}</span>`;
    });
```

for example: when i write "**lookman**" my code above also matches the "**man**" in the word "look**man**"

what I want is that when I type **"lookman"** it doesn't match **"man"**.

I hope I asked the right question (with the rules) thanks in advance

Comment: You can add word boundaries (`\b`) to the ends of the regex, so it would look like `/\b(...)\b/`.

Comment: where do i paste this in my code ? @kelly

Comment: It would be when you're generating the regex ```let searchRgx = new RegExp(this.highlightWordList.map(item => {
      console.log(item)
      return '\\b(' + item.highWord + ')\\b';
    }).join("|"), 'gi');```

Comment: thanks a lot sir if you post this as an answer i can confirm it's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on the comment from kelly

You can add word boundries `\b`. Updating the line where you're generating the regex

```
let searchRgx = new RegExp(this.highlightWordList.map(item => {
    console.log(item)       
    return '\\b(' + item.highWord + ')\\b'; 
    // Another string formatting option:  `\\b(${item.highWord})\\b`    
}).join("|"), 'gi');
```

Comment: I would like to ask one more question if you are available. //B character does not match Turkish characters, how can I fix it? For example;it matches when typed
 danış"man"ı but daniş"man" works correctly when typing @Quantum-pie

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand your question. But if you're expecting something like danışmanı to not match because of the ş character. You can update the regex to also check for specific Turkish characters, replace `\\b` with `[^a-zA-Zşı]` expanding as needed. Another option is `\\b` to `(?:\\s|^)(MAN)(?:\\s|$)` where \\s is white space and ^,$ are the start and end of the string